# active directory windows 2008 domain logon

Tags: directory

I have a system that is configured to logon to a domain say abc.net. I dont have admin access to this system. The AD server is dead.

If i can create an active directory server on the same network as the original one means same ip address and same domain name and create a user account there can i login successfully?

Comment: What are you trying to do? if its data recovery there are a few other ways to do this.

Comment: Cynical: What have you done, nicked a laptop and you're trying to get data off it or something?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, no.

Without going into too much detail, pretty much everything in Active Directory has a GUID, which by definition won't be the same after a re-install. The GUID of your domain and computer object will not match, so even with the same "human friendly" names you will be unable to logon.

If you need to get Active Directory running again so all users and computers that existed on the dead server come back, you will need to do an Active Directory restoration. This is also why you have more than one Domain Controller.

If you simply need data off the computer you have, boot into a live CD of some description and pull files off that way.